# sscanf function usage in c

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to parse `xxxxxx(xxxxx)` format string using `sscanf` as following:

```
sscanf(command, "%s(%s)", part1, part2)
```

but it seems like `sscanf` does not support this format and as a result, `part1` actually contains the whole string.

anyone has experience with this please share...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting your code into a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char part1[32];
    char part2[32];
    char command[32] = "xxxxx(yyyy)";
    int n;

    if ((n = sscanf(command, "%s(%s)", part1, part2)) != 2)
        printf("Problem! n = %d\n", n);
    else
        printf("Part1 = <<%s>>; Part2 = <<%s>>\n", part1, part2);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, it produces '`Problem! n = 1`'.

This is because the first `%s` conversion specifier skips leading white space and then scans for 'non white-space' characters up to the next white space character (or, in this case, end of string).

You would need to use (negated) character classes or *scansets* to get the result you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char part1[32];
    char part2[32];
    char command[32] = "xxxxx(yyyy)";
    int n;

    if ((n = sscanf(command, "%31[^(](%31[^)])", part1, part2)) != 2)
        printf("Problem! n = %d\n", n);
    else
        printf("Part1 = <<%s>>; Part2 = <<%s>>\n", part1, part2);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
Part1 = <<xxxxx>>; Part2 = <<yyyy>>
```

Note the 31's in the format; they prevent overflows.

---

> I'm wondering how does %31 works. Does it work as `%s` and prevent overflow or does it just prevent overflow?

With the given data, these two lines are equivalent and both safe enough:

```
    if ((n = sscanf(command, "%31[^(](%31[^)])", part1, part2)) != 2)
    if ((n = sscanf(command, "%[^(](%[^)])", part1, part2)) != 2)
```

The `%[...]` notation is a conversion specification; so is `%31[...]`.

The C standard says:

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %.
>   After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> - An optional assignment-suppressing character *.
> - An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the maximum field width
>     (in characters).
> - An optional length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving object.
> - A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of conversion to be applied.

The 31 is an example of the (optional) maximum field width.  The `[...]` part is a *scanset*, which could perhaps be regarded as a special case of the `s` conversion specifier.  The `%s` conversion specifier is approximately equivalent to `%[^ \t\n]`.

The 31 is one less than the length of the string; the null at the end is not counted in that length.  Since `part1` and `part2` are each an array of 32 `char`, the `%31[^(]` or `%31[^)]` conversion specifiers prevent buffer overflows. If the first string of characters was more than 31 characters before the `(`, you'd get a return value of 1 because of a mismatch on the literal open parenthesis.  Similarly, the second string would be limited to 31 characters, but you'd not easily be able to tell whether the `)` was in the correct place or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm wondering how does %31 works. Does it works as %s and prevent overflow or does it just prevent overflow, sscanf read string by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you know exactly how long are the parts of your "command", then the simplest option is:

```
sscanf(command, "%6s(%5s)", part1, part2);
```

This assumes that 'part1' is always 6 characters long and 'part2' is always 5 characters long (as in your code sample).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str1[20];
  char str2[20];
  sscanf("Hello(World!)", "%[^(](%[^)])", str1, str2);
  printf("str1=\"%s\", str2=\"%s\"\n", str1, str2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/w8k74)):

```
str1="Hello", str2="World!"
```

Comment: If you scan user input, you're being for an exploit.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm aware of security issues of simple-minded code.